# Интерфейс с generic аргументом, полиморфизм

Tags: c#, интерфейс, generics

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Нужно в один словарь поместить различные объекты реализующие один интерфейс с generic аргументом.

Вот код для примера:

Есть интерфейс параметра и две реализации **OneParameter** и **TwoParameter**:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ParameterBase : IParameter
{
    public ParameterBase(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class OneParameter : ParameterBase
{
    public OneParameter(int oneProperty)
        : base("One")
    {
        OneProperty = oneProperty;
    }

    public int OneProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TwoParameter : ParameterBase
{
    public TwoParameter(int twoProperty)
        : base("Two")
    {
        TwoProperty = twoProperty;
    }

    public int TwoProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Также есть две стратегии поведения:

```
public interface IRequestStrategy<TRequestParameter>
    where TRequestParameter : IParameter
{
    Task RequestDocument(TRequestParameter parameter);
}

public class OneRequestStrategy : IRequestStrategy<OneParameter>
{
    public Task RequestDocument(OneParameter parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TwoRequestStrategy : IRequestStrategy<TwoParameter>
{
    public Task RequestDocument(TwoParameter parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Далее пытаюсь зарегистрирровать стратегии в одном словаре:

```
private static void TestStrategies()
    {
        Dictionary<int, IRequestStrategy<IParameter>> _strategies = 
            new Dictionary<int, IRequestStrategy<IParameter>>();

        var str1 = new OneRequestStrategy();
        var str2 = new TwoRequestStrategy();

        _strategies.Add(1, (IRequestStrategy<IParameter>)str1);
        _strategies.Add(2, str2);
    }
```

При этом в первом случае ошибка приведения типов:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'OneRequestStrategy' to type IRequestStrategy`1[IParameter]'.
```

Ну и во втором тоже самое только при компиляции:

```
Error   CS1503  : cannot convert from 'TwoRequestStrategy' to 'IRequestStrategy<IParameter>'
```

Comment: Читайте про ковариантность и контраариантность и запомните, что `IRequestStrategy<TRequestParameter>` , `IRequestStrategy<OneParameter>` и `IRequestStrategy<TwoParameter>` - это все три совершенно разных типа.

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку, не знал про ковариантность и контраариантность интерфейсов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать маркер интерфейс:

```
public interface IRequestStrategy{}
```

Добавляем его в наследники:

```
public interface IRequestStrategy<TRequestParameter>
  : IRequestStrategy
  where TRequestParameter : IParameter
```

Потом в словаре храним вот так:

```
Dictionary<int, IRequestStrategy> _strategies = 
  new Dictionary<int, IRequestStrategy>();
```

А при доставании из словаря нужно будет проверять типы или использовать паттерн Visitor.